# How to split html string using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am having a function takes a string input. the string input is noting but a group of html tags like below

```
<section><div><span><bold></bold></span></div></section>
```

and i want the output to be like below

```
["<section>","<div>","<span>","<bold>","</bold>","</span>","</div>","</section>"]
```

guys pls help me how to split the html string to an array

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can use regex and `.match()` to do this.

Demo:

```js
var text = "<section><div><span><bold></bold></span></div></section>";
console.log(text.match(/\<.*?\>/g))
```

Answer (score 5):

The following approach will also work,

```js
let str = "<section><div><span><bold></bold></span></div></section>";
let newstr = str.replace(/</gi, "<><");
let res = newstr.split("<>").filter(v => v != "");
console.log(res)
```